# Repository is Nothing but added in the container later (correctly) (using Unity, Repositories) in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

I have a "MenuService", which uses an "MenuRepository".

When the MenuService is created, it loads correctly with the MenuRepository.
Then it wants to save it in the UnityControllerFactory, but the MenuRepository in the MenuService is Nothing then (it wasn't before).

Very strange.

Does anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Some additional info:
I'm using the Unity and Repository pattern.
The problem happens with a partial view (for a menu), which i have included in the "HomeController", it could be relevant information, so i included this, just in case:

```
Function Menu() As ActionResult
    Return PartialView("~\Views/Shared/_Menu.vbhtml", _MenuService.GetAllMenuItems)
End Function
```

Also, my partial "menu" view is like this:
~/_Menu.vbhtml

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of FacturatieMVCv2.Domain.Slave.MenuItem)

@*<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">*@
<ul>

@For Each Item In Model.Where(Function(el) IsNothing(el.HasHigherMenuItem))
@<li> @Html.ActionLink(Item.Naam,Item.Action,Item.Controller)
  <ul>
@For Each SubItem In Model.Where(Function(el) el.HasHigherMenuItem.MenuItemID.Equals(Item.MenuItemID))
      @<li>
            @Html.ActionLink(SubItem.Naam,SubItem.Action,SubItem.Controller)
      </li>
    Next
      </ul>                               
</li>
Next
</ul>
```

And i'm calling the partial view with:

```
@Html.Action("Menu","Home")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your IoC before your application starts and you need to get your service from IoC.

This [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/24/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-unity-application-block.aspx) will help you a lot.

I this case repository dependencies in the service will be resolved by IoC (Unity)

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, i already have a unity container in my global.asax loading, worked fine for other services. This is the first one where i have a problem with, although i'm not sure of the second part of the article, i'm trying it out now :)

Comment: Do you instantiate your services using IoC?

Comment: Yes, i use IoC, which is also used in my global.asax to bind the repositories and services to the httpcontext :).
Finished reading the article and everything that is described there is implemented in my code (and working).
Except this MenuService ... :(

Comment: it's must be error somewhere :) Maybe in the types registration or somewhere else. I can't find the error because I don't have your codebase.

Comment: do you using the same repository with the any other services? and vice versa, in  this service any other repositories?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3057/discussion-between-nicojuicy-and-samich)

Comment: Article was helpfull for some insight, had a stupid mistake which i didn't notice (looked to far away, while the solution was in front of me)...
Sorry for the trouble and thank you very much for the effort, appreciate it :)